# Do we need the [turbo] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [turbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turbo) (3 questions) is completely useless.

The tag wiki says:

> The Turbo button was a toggle switch present on older personal computers that enabled systems to run at faster/slower speeds.

But *none* of the questions is actually about that, and the meaning is ambiguous. Burninate ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, That was quick :-)

Comment: Catching it early is the right way to do these things.  Once a tag gets 1000 questions, it's too late.

Comment: [You're not going Turbo, are you?](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0306905/quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the tag is now burninated, thanks to Robert Harvey !

[image: Burninated!]

---